# How to read two files and closing the first one properly? C++

Tags: c++

I created two files 
the first one contains : 1 2 3 4;
the second contains: 5 6 7 8
I'm attempting to read the second file after the other, but instead of reading the second file, it reads the first one again despite the fact that I closed it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using  namespace std;

int main()

{

    ifstream  inFile;
     inFile.clear();
    inFile.open("text1.txt");

    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error Opening File "<< endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int first1, second1, third1, last1;

    inFile >> first1 >> second1 >> third1 >> last1;


    cout 
<< first1 << " " << second1 << " " << third1  <<  " "<<  last1 << endl;

    inFile.close();




    ifstream  inFile1;
     inFile1.clear();
    inFile1.open("text2.txt");

    if (inFile1.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error Opening File "<< endl;
        exit(1);
    }

   int first2, second2, third2, last2;

    inFile >> first2 >> second2 >> third2 >> last2;


    cout 
<< first2 << " " << second2 << " " << third2  <<  " "<<  last2 << endl;

    inFile1.close();






    return 0;
}
```

it prints

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

instead of

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the data from inFile, the second time, instead of inFile1.

```
inFile >> first2 >> second2 >> third2 >> last2;
```